# Android app supporting different languages through locale folders vs making stand-alone apps, which is better?

Tags: android, localization

What are the advantages (or disadvantages) of having your android app supporting different languages by using the local folders vs releasing the same app in different languages (other than that it takes a little extra time)?

Comment: Are you planning also to release different apps for different screen sizes and densities, for example...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are countless reasons to use Android's built-in localization features.
Here's a small sampling:

- **Users can change their language at will.** The app will automatically choose the correct language without the user downloading the app again
- **You get a single codebase.** This greatly simplifies your code
  organization.
- **You only need one APK.** You don't waste time exporting and uploading one APK for every language you support
- **Integration with the development tools.** Android Lint will warn you if you missed translating a String.

Going with your own method of localizing your app is the naive way to localize. Ignoring Android's powerful tools for supporting different devices and localization settings will only create more work for yourself.